# When writing mutual information chain rule in terms of entropies, almost all terms cancel out. Is this correct?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

The chain rule for mutual information:

$$I(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n; Y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(X_i; Y| X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}, ..., X_1)$$

If we rewrite this in terms of entropy, using the identities
$$ I(X;Y|Z) = H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z) $$
and
$$I(X;Y) = I(Y;X)$$ 
we seem to get:

$$I(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n; Y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} H(Y| X_{i-1}, X_{i-2}, ..., X_1)-H(Y|X_{i}, X_{i-1}, ..., X_1)$$

which results in all but two terms canceling:

$$H(Y) - H(Y|X_n, ..., X_1)$$

This seems obviously wrong, but I can't seem to find out where I went wrong.

Comment: Is the end result not simply $I(Z;Y) = H(Y) - H(Y \mid Z)$ for $Z = (X_1, \ldots,X_n)$?

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten that you can just aggregate variables in that manner. So math is working as intended and I haven't made a silly mistake?